# How can I politely express that "I have understood"?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, politeness, email

When my professor instructs me during his/her office hour, I may simply show my understanding by "Got it" or "I see". But I wonder how to say that politely and professionally in written English, especially in an email.

Comment: There are also the [ell.se] and the [workplace.se] for the interested. Please take a look at them as well.

Comment: "Sure, that makes sense."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically when writing a polite and formal message or email; a longer sentence will sound more courteous and gracious than a two word reply.

There are innumerable ways of writing a polite acknowledgement, or a thank-you note. Change the adjectives with ones that you feel more comfortable with.

You can use the verb, **grasp**, instead of *understand* to say you comprehended something fully, and you won't easily forget or be confused by it again.

> - Thank you so much for your clear and unambiguous explanations on [topic]. They
>     have helped me tremendously.
> - I really appreciated your explanations in the last session I
>     attended, they helped me to grasp/understand [topic] and now I feel much more confident. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

What's wrong with "I understand." or simply "Understood."?

These are perfectly professional but also not stuffy.

Answer (score 3):

Often the best way to indicate that you have understood is to summarize in one sentence *what* your understanding will lead you to do next.

> e.g., "I understand.  I will get back to you with the revisions you requested by Monday."

or

> "I see.  I will make sure to include or discuss your idea that .... in my next paper."

Comment: Thank you! Another question though, how formal is the phrase "I see"? Could I use it in an semi-official email?

Comment: "I see" is medium formality.  But you have to be careful because sometimes it can be sarcastic (="oh, you really think that?!" or "that's not the answer I was expecting").  It depends on what you say next.  It is probably better used in speech.

Comment: "I see" is also a shortening of the more formal phrasing "I see what you are saying."

Answer (score 1):

As in written form, there is no specific way to display politeness, the choice of words is all that can convey mood. Though, there are always ways to be more professional.

In an email, you could say "Thanks for the help, I have understood the subject."

This sounds polite (with "thanks" being used) and professional.

Answer (score 1):

> Understood, thanks.

or

> I understand, thanks.

Is clear, and polite.